# How to fix Google oauth verification error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-oauth, google-signin

When I sent my application to Google oauth team, they said it's a developing or staging application and these are not allowed for oauth login. And the thing is I already published my application a month ago. And also added a download button for it on my website
Here is a pic-
[What they mailed me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp2Gv.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure the email/reply itself is self-explanatory.
"Google" thinks that your application itself is not complete and is still in development. Please try to contact google support team regarding this. That is all I can say from the amount of information you have given.

Comment: Does google download my application???

Comment: I have no clue regarding this. I myself am in the process of development.
Is I said before, just email the folks at Google. They will be able to give you the best answer.